# Design pattern usage

Tags: c#, design-patterns, decorator, strategy-pattern

I have the following design:

- I create a class containing properties (like a very big array)
- Later when I parse the file I want some 'extra parameters/functionality' added, based on the content of the properties in above.

What is the best solution?

1. Derive a class with the extra parameters/functionality (problem: need to copy the big array to the new class)
2. Decorator pattern? Or is a decorator not meant for adding extra properties/functions?
3. Strategy pattern? Since I need properties likely not usable.
4. Another solution?

Comment: Why would the derived class need a copy of what's in the parent class?  The point of inheritance is that you *don't* need to copy the code.  You might also try composition instead of inheritance... The new class can contain an instance of the existing class instead of becoming an instance of it, if that conceptually applies to the data being modeled that is.  (Which is pretty much Decorator, I guess, depending on how you model it.)  I'm not sure how Strategy even applies here, since that's directed at *algorithms* and not *data models*, unless your description of the object is incomplete...

Comment: @David The reason is that the original (parent) class is already created before I can check if I need the derived class (instance). But what you say regarding the decorator part is a good point, I think I use that way (or try how it works).

Comment: As it appears that you want to compose your classes 'based on the content of the properties in above' decoration is the solution that will allow this dynamic composition. Inheritance would mean that you would have to select the appropriate derivation without knowing which derivation you actually needed.

Comment: Ah, in that case without knowing more it definitely sounds like Decorator is the way to go.  The new object simply wraps the old one and delegates some functionality to it.  How much you want to obscure that delegation is up to you.  This also fits well with the notion of favoring composition over inheritance, which I believe was advised in the Gang of Four book.

Comment: @David Thanks, looks indeed like the decorator pattern is the best... if you can add it as answer I can acknowledge that one (if you want).

Comment: +1 for Decorator/Proxy/Wrapping/Whatever you want to call it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class for `AdditionalValues`, add one instance to your array and when you need the new values you can set them to the given object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I would like the class properties to be available from both (normal and 'additional' object). Which probably looks most like the decorator pattern as @David already explained (still given +1 for a possible answer).

Comment: You have the "normal" object and there is an array inside. The array contains the additional object, so you can reach the additional object of the normal object through its array.

Comment: I think I was unclear than .... the array contains bytes, and the additional object should be a separate object with own methods and properties.

Comment: Then you can add the additional object to the "normal" object as a member instead of putting it into the array.

Comment: True, but I have a good reason to have two different objects (one without, one with additional data). Because it is dependent of the content of the file if I need that. In OO, it's not a good idea to have classes with properties/functions not used but still be there.

Comment: "In OO, it's not a good idea to have classes with properties/functions not used but still be there." You use your additional object when you need it and have null as default value. It is too much hurdle to implement another class which has the additional member and convert your objects back and forth. You would use too much resources to comply to an abstract OOP rule. I believe you would sacrifice too much in practice.

Comment: True ... however I think I go for the (minimal?) decorator solution ... if that does not work your solution might work best.

Comment: Yes, the decorator solution is feasible as well.